# setInterval and displaying objects in an array against a timeline

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need help creating an efficient JS listener against an array of objects and a video.  It works, but is really inefficient and memory intensive, especially if the array of objects is large.

I have a video that is 1 minute long and I want to display objects that are synchronized with this video on the GUI based on timecodes.  For example, at 0:23, I want to display a comment.

The synchronized, timecoded objects are stored in an array like this:

```
comm1 = {text : "I like it", time : 23}
comm2 = {text : "I hate it", time : 48}
comm3 = {text : "I love it", time : 59}

var arr = [comm1, comm2, comm3]
```

I then have a Flash video player that returns the current playhead position of the video.  I can call it through JavaScript like so:

```
var position = document.getElementById("player").currentTime();
```

I then created a setInterval object that loops through the array every 250 ms to display the comment like so:

```
function getCurrentComment(){
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(position >= arr[i].time){    
            getId("comments").innerHTML = arr[i].text;              
        }
    }
}

var commListener = setInterval("getCurrentComment()", 250);
```

This works visually, but in reality, it continues to execute the "getId("comments").innerHTML = arr[i].text" line of code every 250 ms no matter what.  Is there better way to do this without having to continuously loop through an array?  It gets really bad when there are 100+ objects in the array.  I was looking at the Observer Pattern but I don't think it will work for this since I'm synchronizing in real time with a video.

Comment: try looping backwards, and break out of the loop after you update the html.

Comment: Is there any way you can listen for manual scrubbing? That way, there's no need for a loop.

Comment: I can't depend on the seek because if the end user lets the video play straight through without seeking, the comments should display in sync with the video as well.  If I break out of the loop, at what point should it start back up?

Comment: I can help you out with that. If you say that you can listen to know whether the user is manually seeking, I'll provide you with a solution.

Comment: yes, I can listen for the seek event.  I'm interested to know what your solution is.

Comment: @Freddie - I posted my answer below. Let me know what you think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can listen to the seek event, then you can do something like this:

```
var arr = [
        {text : "I like it", time : 23},
        {text : "I hate it", time : 48},
        {text : "I love it", time : 59}
    ],
    ceil = arr.length - 1,
    current = 0,
    el = getId("comments"),
    commListener;

function commListenerFunc()
{
    commListener = setInterval(function ()
    {
        if (arr[current].time == position)
        {
            el.innerHTML = arr[current].text;

            if ( current < ceil )
            {
                current++;
            }
            else
            {
                clearInterval( commListener );
            }
        }

    }, 250);
}

// Call this function on the seek event
function seekCallback()
{
    clearInterval( commListener );

    current = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < ceil; i++)
    {
        if ( arr[i + 1].time < position )
        {
            current++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    commListenerFunc();
}

commListenerFunc();
```

**Please note:** I did not debug this code, and it might have some issues. I'm just posting it here to give you the general idea...

Comment: am taking a look now... i'll let you know how it goes in a moment

Comment: Joseph - this worked like a charm.  What I can't get my head around is how the the interval breaks within the commListener?  I tracked it and the current++ is triggered and the interval stops without ever reaching the clearInterval command.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Freddie - I'm not following you completely. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTrSb/), and let me know if you've still got any issues.

Comment: Joseph - it works really well.  I just wanted to know more about the code, but I understand it now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your `arr` and set `var nextComm = 0`, you can just test against the `arr[nextComm]`. If that one gets displayed, increment `nextComm`. If there's a seek, find the appropriate `nextComm` by seeking through arr for the closest future match.

Also, don't set `innerHtml` when you don't have to.

Comment: And also do the `getId("comments")` outside of the loop, that might be the most expensive operation.